# Download image from Webview

Tags: webview, uwp

Is it possible to download an image that the user clicked on in a `WebView`? Or at least handle the click inside a `WebView` to get the URL of the image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UWP `WebView` has a `InvokeScriptAsync` method that can invoke a JavaScript function including parameters. However, you can execute any JavaScript code by using the `"eval"` function as the first parameter and your arbitrary JS code as the second parameter. When I do this, I usually store the JS code in a `.js` content file in the package and then read its content and just pass it in, but you can equally well hardcode the JavaScript code into a string directly.

After the `WebView` navigates, you could use this method to execute a JS snippet that registers an `onclick` event on all images in the DOM.

The tricky part is the event handler, because you need to pass the clicked image's URL to your code. To do that you could use `ScriptNotify` event of the `WebView`, but that works only if you know the URLs the user will browse beforehand and if they are all SSL enabled.

A universal solution is a web-allowed object, which is a C# class that must live in a Windows Runtime Component library and be `sealed` and have `[AllowForWeb]` attribute. You "inject" an instance of this class into the `WebView` and on which you can execute methods from JS code. You can find an example [here](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Universal-Windows-App-bf423aee) or [here](https://github.com/boyofgreen/Win10WebViewCallCSharp).